# Is $\mathbb{C}\bigotimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}\simeq \mathbb{C}\bigotimes_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

I'm trying to see if for several cases changing the ring in a tensor product affects the result or doesn't. Now I'm trying to prove  $\mathbb{C}\bigotimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}\simeq \mathbb{C}\bigotimes_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}$ if it's true, or to show why it isn't.

I've been unable to find an isomporphism between those two, but I don't know how would I proceed in order to show that there is no possible function that could define one.

Comment: Hint: There is a nice formula for the dimension of a tensor product of vector spaces.

Comment: This same question was asked less than a month ago, it's most definitely a duplicate.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Nowadays questions are flooding into the forum, it is not easy even to find a problem posted three days ago.

Comment: As long as there is not a definite list with edited, agreed on names, it can be almost impossible to find old questions, as John remarks. There are even question answered by me or by someone I very well know that I just can't find.

Comment: @john I know what you mean, but actually I rarely have difficulty finding duplicates with the search and/or google. Questions like this are harder though since they've got lots of tex in them. Anyway, I hope you weren't advocating for giving up on duplicate searches before posting questions. It would really be better for posters to have that habit.

Comment: @timbuc you might have better luck doing a google search with "site:math.stackexchange.com" appended

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you, I shall try that next time.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks. I've been using the search bar to look for duplicate with moderate results, I've been unable to find some questions because of the latex code (which doesn't seem to work with the search bar) and I wouldn't how to write the without it (for example using symbols for direct sums, tensor product,etc).
Should I delete the questions since it's a duplicate?

Comment: @Cure No, it's OK to leave this question. It is just another net that will help catch people looking for the same question. But do your best to avoid duplicating questions in the future :) Unavoidable duplication occurs if questions are titled poorly. Eventually we'll collect a sufficient number of titles to deter duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an isomorphism of rings $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ (Hint: Use $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ and then CRT), but $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C}$. So these are not isomorphic rings, since $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ has zero divisors for example. But they are isomorphic $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, since the dimension is $c$ (continuum) in each case.

Comment: I think you mean $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces.